# mobile navbar is not displaying inline instead of vertically when using display: inline-block in media queries?

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

When I put display: inline block in media queries section in css in does not display my nav horizontally inline and instead displays in vertically like before. I am starting out coding and I am trying to create a mobile first website, which expands to a inline navigation when over a min-width.

Here is my html:

```
<header> 
    
    <nav class="navbar"> 
        <img src="images.png" alt="logo" class="logo"> 
        <a href="mobile" id="icon" title="Mobile menu"></a>
            <ul class="nav-list"> 
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html"> Home </a></li>      
            <li><a href="snow.html"> Snow </a></li>
            <li><a href="skate.html"> Skate </a></li> 
            <li><a href="accessories.html"> Accessories </a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav> 
    
  

</header>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.navbar{ 
        align-items: center;
        height: 175px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #FFF;
        z-index: 999;
        position: fixed;
        

    }
    .nav-list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .nav-list li { 
    line-height: 15px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    transition: auto;

    }
    .nav-list li a { 
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 23px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        display: block;
    }


    .nav-list li a.active,.nav-list li a:hover{ 
        transition: 0.75s; 
        color: #702963;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .navbar ul.nav-list { 
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: var(--grey);
        list-style: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }



@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) { 
        body, .navbar ul.nav-list, .navlist a, .navlist li {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
            
        } 
    }
```

I tried display: inline block did not display horizontally. flex-direction: row; does not change to row either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `flex-direction` works if you set `display: flex`. Please try changing the css in your `@media` to the following:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
  .navbar ul.nav-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help!